# Missing 'Expression' option in 'Random Points in Polygon' tool

Tags: qgis, python, versioning

I am running QGIS Desktop version 3.8.2
I need to use the 'Random Points in Polygon' tool as part of a process.
The number of points per polygon is defined by one of the fields so I simply add that field name in the 'expression' option and it works without issues.
[image: ToolInterface]

My colleague who is runnning QGIS Desktop version 3.10.2 needs to run the same process as me however her version of the tool does not have the 'Expression' parameter.

[image]

I have tried sharing the tool python script but that errors as the parameter 'EXPRESSION' is not recognised.

Can I locate and share my version of the tool?

Comment: No, you can't. But when clicking the grey box to the right of the "point cound or density" field you may choose "edit" and enter any valid expression there.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly.